# How to use styles in Angular for whole application angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want at the Angular App at the styles to create the general style and when I create components just to use in HTML, it is that possible ?
I tried like this but didn't work.

```
@import "../../styles";
```

I am taking this error.

[Here is the Photo to show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZtBz.png)

Comment: If you use angular cli just put the styles in the global styles.scss file. But it's cleaner to have style broken down in components imho

Comment: I declared in the angular cli... but still not working

Comment: Imports only work with scss files,  not css. Besides that styles.scss file is global and already applies to all your app, you don't need to import it

Comment: Thanks man for your time I fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change from

```
@import "../../styles";
```

to

```
@import "../../styles.css";
```

and this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.angular-cli.json` in the root folder of your project. It should contain this part:

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "my-other-global-steylesheets.css"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

or add them to the `<head>` section in your `index.html`, for example:

```html
<head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The explizit import to every component's stylesheet is not required in most cases. That might increase the app size unnecessarily.

[See more in the Angular CLI wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)

Comment: Thank you for time but I have fixed this.